# How to bind a TreeView Hierarchically by using enum values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

Ok, so I am not sure this is even possible but I will ask the question here and hope to get an answer to it.

Suppose I have a list of a class, say Media items defined as follows

```
Enum MediaItemType{
  Book,
  CD,
  VideoGame
}

public MediaItem{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public MediaItemType { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose I want to bind a list of MediaItems to a TreeView such that each MediaItem ends upp in a separate subtree depending on the media item type. Is that possible to do and if so, how do I do that?

In my Xaml-code I assume that I have defined the list as a property named MediaItems in the context.

```
<Grid>
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MediaItems}">
</Grid>
```

The tree view should be something like this

```
Book
  - In to the wild
  - Code Complete
CD
  - Foo Fighters
  - Bach
DVD
  - X-men
  - Casino Royale
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about about a tree view, but you could achieve something similar to what you describe using a GroupDescription grouping on the MediaItemType property with a ListBox or ListView as described [here](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/wpf-sample-series-listbox-grouping-sorting-subtotals-and-collapsible-regions/)

Comment: Ok, thanks perhaps I should use the ListBox instead in this case. I guess that will give me the same result as I wanted with the Treeview.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any problem.
In model you have `MediaItem`, on model view you have to have `MediaItemView` type, something like this:

```
public class MediaItemView
{
    public MediaItemType { get; set; }
    public List<MediaItem> medialist;
}
```

Define bindings on that class, and define a `Converter` which will convert `enum` value to its `string` presentation.

Comment: Ok, but from what I understand I still have to sort the list according to MediaItemType. I was hoping not to do that. What happens for example when I add a new item or itemtype for example?

Comment: If you add new MediaItem, nothing changes cause you continue to split entities on colleciton based on  MediaItemTypes defined. The same is actually for new MediaItemType: just another more type to consider during the split.